# I can't find my mistake: If $G$ is multiplicative group generated by two matrices, then $H \subset \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is the multiplicative group generated by the matrices $\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.

Since $G$ is abelian it follows that for all integers $m$ and $n$, every matrix in $G$ can be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^m\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}^n = \begin{pmatrix} 2^m & n2^m \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Now suppose that $H \leq G$ such that $H$ contains all matrices in $G$ whose main diagonal entries are $1$. Then if $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ b & 1\end{pmatrix} \in H$, then since $H$ is contained in $G$, there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ b & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2^m & n 2^m\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$
which implies that $2^m = 1, \, a = n2^m,$ and $b = 0$. But because the order of $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is infinite, it follows that $2^m = 1$ if and only if $m = 0$. Therefore,
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a \\ b & 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
so $H \subset \left\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle$.

But I know I went wrong somewhere in my calculations because $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \in H$ but not in $\left\langle \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \right\rangle$, yet I cannot see where I made my mistake. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance

Comment: Your title is provocatively nonsensical, since $H$ seems to have nothing to do with $G$. You might want to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is right at the top: $G$ is not abelian.
$$\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2&0\\
0&1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\ 0&1\end{array}\right) &= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 &2\\ 0& 1\end{array}\right)\\
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&0\\0&1\end{array}\right) &= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1\\0 &1
\end{array}\right).
\end{align*}$$

Left multiplying by an elementary matrix performs elementary row operations; right multiplying performs elementary column operations. So left multiplying by the diagonal matrix multiplies the first *row* by $2$, but right multiplying by it will multiply the first *column* by $2$. Since your other matrix does not have zeros outside the diagonal in the first row and column, it does not commute with it.

Answer (score 4):

$G$ is not abelian because $$\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}\\\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Your structural claim doesn't hold.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I forgot that matrices are not always commutative. Thank you!